# Automatically revert cells to proper format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some gray cells in my spreadsheet that are supposed to accept user input. I have protected all other cells on the sheet:

[image]

I want to prevent endusers from changing the cell formatting (background color, borders, merged cells).

The main issue is when the user pastes content from another spreadsheet because the paste carries along with it all of the formatting from the other spreadsheet and un-merges/un-colors cells.

I am trying to do it with onEdit(e), and revert the active cell's formatting. One problem is that if you paste in a GROUP of cells, "e.range" is wrong and displaced:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  Browser.msgBox(row + "," + col); // wrong on multi-cell paste
}
```

Another approach is to have a clone hidden sheet and constantly copy content from it onto the active sheet, but due to the protections I mentioned, it takes a while to run because it has to iterate through all unprotected cells.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you store the format for the paste range in another range on another sheet and then us copyFormatToRange to reformat it back to the way it was after every paste in the onEdit trigger function?

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Cooper ! I tried to do something similar with the cloned hidden sheet, but what I think you are suggesting is only storing and rebuilding specific input boxes that the user is editing/pasting on. I will give it a try. I am concerned about the fact that it is difficult to know which cell the user is working on because pasting a group of cells will offset onEdit's e.range, but I might be able to do what you recommend by using named ranges and restoring all named ranges in the active sheet.

Comment: Or just save the formatting for the whole sheet.

Comment: This is what I was trying to explain in my question's last paragraph. Your idea of reformatting specific cells may be a solution - I am about to try it. For doing it for the whole sheet, I cannot paste the entire hidden sheet's format onto the visible sheet because the visible sheet is protected except certain cells. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you paste them.  I think you should use range.copyFormatToRange. Look it up on the [range page for spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyFormatToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer). You can add it to you onEdit routine perhaps.